# Why does jScrollPane work in every 'modern' browser except IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jscrollpane

I have put in the new [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html), and I've gotten my scrollbars to work on every browser except IE8! Same thing happened with the old version as well. I keep getting this error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 22 Sep 2010 14:14:38 UTC

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 4618
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js?ver=3.0.1
```

When I pull up the demo's page on my IE8, it works fine.
Also, nothing weird in my call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#content').jScrollPane({
        showArrows: true,
        verticalDragMinHeight: 20,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 20
    });
});
```

Content's css is:

```
#content {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah - it's hard to say what is going wrong without a demo page. I can't see anything incorrect in the code above...

Comment: http://www.nancymedwell.com?page_id=609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a couple of things:

- Move your initialisation scripts into the HEAD. Since they are inside document.ready blocks anyway it doesn't have any effect putting them inline at the bottom of the body.
- Try commenting out other scripts to see if they are causing problem. Since you had the same problem with two versions of jScrollPane which use completely different code it seems that the problem may be related to something else on your page.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, the javascript error still shows up, but so does the scrollbar